# Qt on Android Runtime error: Invalid package identifier when getting bag for resource number 0x00000000

Tags: java, android, c++, qt

I am getting this strange error after updating my Qt version from 5.13.1 to 5.14.2 and I am not sure what is the cause of it (I also updated my gradle version from 4.1.0 to 5.5.1). The error give the following output message:

> W ResourceType: Invalid package identifier when getting bag for
>   resource number 0x00000000 E Qt      : Can't create main activity E Qt
>   : android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array
>   resource ID #0x0 E Qt      :  at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getStringArray(Resources.java:525) E Qt 
>   :     at
>   org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtLoader.startApp(QtLoader.java:423)
>   E Qt      :   at
>   org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivityLoader.onCreate(QtActivityLoader.java:166)
>   E Qt      :   at
>   org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreateHook(QtActivity.java:266)
>   E Qt      :   at
>   org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.onCreate(QtActivity.java:273)

I have seen that this has been discussed before, but the solution given were unrelated to Qt and required the modification of Java code (which I don't think it is the problem at all in my case since I haven't changed that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it turns out that Qt 5.14 requires an updated version of the AndroidManifest.xml file of a project. This is mentioned here [Qt for Android known issues](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Android_known_issues). The needed changes can be found at the following [link](https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtandroidextras/+/278987/2/examples/androidextras/notification/android-sources/AndroidManifest.xml).

After updating the manifest file, my project runs correctly.

Answer (score 8):

Qt 5.14 requires a different `AndroidManifest.xml` file than Qt 5.13 or earlier. I followed the [Qt recommendations](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Android_known_issues) and ended up with the following changes to get it to work again:

1. In `AndroidManifest.xml`, add attribute `android:extractNativeLibs="true"` into the `<application …>` element.
2. In `AndroidManifest.xml`, remove the following three lines (shown abbreviated):

   ```
   <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_in_lib_resource_id" … />
   <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_in_assets_resource_id" … />
   <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_libs" … />
   ```
3. In `AndroidManifest.xml`, insert the following line among the other `<meta-data …/>` lines:

   ```
   <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/load_local_libs"/>
   ```
4. In `res/values/libs.xml` in your Android config directory, insert the following lines into the `<resources> … </resources>` element:

   ```
   <array name="load_local_libs">
       <!-- %%INSERT_LOCAL_LIBS%% -->
   </array>
   ```

**Using Qt 5.14 and ≤5.13 in parallel.** Some more detail about this issue is available in issue [QTBUG-80444](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-80444). From there, unfortunately it seems that the required changes are not backwards compatible with Qt 5.13 or earlier, means you need one version of `AndroidManifest.xml` to build for Android with Qt 5.13 and another version to build with Qt 5.14. (Except you never want to look back to Qt 5.13, of course.)

**Sources.** Derived from the [Qt examples diff](https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtandroidextras/+/278987/2/examples/androidextras/notification/android-sources/AndroidManifest.xml) mentioned by @daljit97 in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61102958) on this page. That still lead to an error "`AndroidManifest.xml:80: error: resource array/load_local_libs (aka com.example.qtws:array/load_local_libs) not found.`" on deployment, but [this comment](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-80444?focusedCommentId=496331&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-496331) hinted me into the right direction to fix that.